# mock mvc check that object doesn't exist in session

Tags: spring-mvc, session, spring-boot, integration-testing, mockmvc

I have th following test

```
@Test
public void exitTest() throws Exception {
    mvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
            .get("/exit")
            .sessionAttr(CardController.CREDIT_CARD, mock(CreditCard.class))
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().is(302))
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/")).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.model().attributeDoesNotExist(CardController.CREDIT_CARD));

}
```

I want to check that `CardController.CREDIT_CARD` doesn't exist in session after request.

Does my code correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    .get("/exit")
            .sessionAttr(CardController.CREDIT_CARD, mock(CreditCard.class))
            .accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML))
            .andExpect(status().is(302))
            .andExpect(view().name("redirect:/"))
            .andReturn()
            .getRequest()
            .getSession();

    assertNull(session.getAttribute(CardController.CREDIT_CARD));
```

Comment: Correct answer.